# Scala reflection: how do I define a case class at runtime and then reference to it?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, compiler-construction, scala-macros

I would like to define a case class at run-time, like for example

```
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val myClass: ClassDef = q"case class Authentication(email: String)".asInstanceOf[ClassDef]
val definedClass  = tb.define(myClass)
```

And then being able to refer to it in another reflection

```
  // Actor code that recognise the defined case object
  val actorCode = q"""
  import akka.actor._
  object HelloActor {
    def props() = Props(new HelloActor())
  }
  class HelloActor() extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case $definedClass(emailParam)  => println("case object instance has been received!")
      case _       => println("None received!")
    }
  }
  return HelloActor.props()
  """
```

Any idea on how to do the trick ?

Comment: That's anyway a bad idea, and missing the point of macro/compile-time meta-programming.

Comment: @cchantep, how would you implement it? Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Because this is basically another form of bytecode manipulation to generate code and wire it together in runtime. There is no way compiler can verify that since by definition everything you are doing in quasiquotes (or rather embedded REPL, quasiquites cannot achieve that) deferring compilation to runtime - in compile time you have glorified `String`s so if there is an error in your code you'll learn only after your runtime code throws in "REPL" because of a typo, type error or something.

Comment: Also your code demonstrates 0 reason why you would need it

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The reason is that I would like to generate the code from a JSON or Yaml specification and spawn the Actors at run-time.

Comment: Forget about it. Quasiquotes are part of the compiler (in older versions compiler plugin) and cannot be used in runtime. Instead of generating code it would make more sense to turn JSON into ADT, pass it into actor constructor and inside have some interpreter. What you are describing (generating code from external input) is reinventing yourself recent log4shell vulnerability.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The idea is that I ingest the JSON specification, I generate Scala code as a string and then I compile and run that generated code with all the security checks I need to do. Any idea on how to define case classes and use them later inside the Actors?

Comment: The best think you can do is to: embed REPL, like Scala REPL or Ammonite, or embed compiler, write files to writeable location and read them with ClassLoader or read how metals performs worksheet evaluation: https://github.com/scalameta/metals/tree/main/metals/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/worksheets

Answer (score 1):

The example that you shown is doable without any compile-time reflection:

```
import akka.actor._

// define extractor object: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html
sealed trait EmailExtractor[A] {
  def unapply(value: A): Option[String]
}
object EmailExtractor {
  
  def of[A](pf: PartialFunction[A, String]) = new EmailExtractor[A] {
    def unapply(value: A): Option[String] = pf.lift(value)
  }
}

// inject difference in behavior via constructor
class HelloActor[A](emailExtractor: EmailExtractor[A]) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case emailExtractor(emailParam) =>
      println("case class instance has been received!")
    case _ => println("None received!")
  }
}
object HelloActor {
  
  def props[A](emailExtractor: EmailExtractor[A]) =
    Props(new HelloActor(emailExtractor))
}

implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()

// you'd have to define message somewhere available to both:
//  * actor you are creating
//  * place where you are sending a message
// anyway, there is no reason to generate a whole new actor because of it

def oneTimeCaseClass1 = {
  case class Message(email: String)
  
  actorSystem.actorOf(HelloActor.props(EmailExtractor.of[Message] {
    case Message(string) => string
  })) ! Message("test@test.com")
}

def oneTimeCaseClass2 = {
  case class Message(email: String)
  
  actorSystem.actorOf(HelloActor.props(EmailExtractor.of[Message] {
    case Message(string) => string
  })) ! Message("test2@test2.com")
}

oneTimeCaseClass1
oneTimeCaseClass2

scala.concurrent.Await.result(
  actorSystem.terminate(),
  scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf
)
```

(See [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QR6uAQTLSDiODnRoFqvIYQ))

Additionally:

- `return` is a bad code practice
- Akka Classic (untyped) is discouraged in favor of Akka Typed
- the value of compile-time reflection lies exactly in the fact that it happens in the compile time - quasiquotes cannot be used in runtime to define new code, that requires a full-fledged compiler combined with a specific way of feeding its output to class loader (so basically embedding REPL) - this is dangerous (it's basically an arbitrary code execution), prone to OOM (because you cannot collect memory if REPL is storing its whole history in memory) and needless

Comment: This solution does not solve my problem: all the code has to be generated through quasiquotes. First I define the case classes, then I use those definitions as Actor Messages.

Comment: Forget about it. Quasiquotes works _only_ in compile time. It is impossible to use them to synthesise new code in runtime. You can create ADT with building blocks, parse input into ADT and have actor change its behavior based on configuration it received in constructor.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Well, maybe I misunderstand something but I guess quasiquotes can work at runtime :)

Comment: If you consider toolbox, yes. But In my dictionary embedding compiler to you app to compile and load code in the runtime is somewhere around generating C code, calling compiler from your code and then dynamically loading resulting .dll/.so file. It is technically true, but that you are in runtime but your runtime did block until compiler created the code that you just loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems almost ok.

You just missed `.companion` in

```scala
val actorCode = q"""
   import akka.actor._
   object HelloActor {
     def props() = Props(new HelloActor())
   }
   class HelloActor() extends Actor {
     def receive = {
       case ${definedClass.companion}(emailParam)  => println("case object instance has been received!")
       case _       => println("None received!")
     }
   }
   ActorSystem("hellokernel").actorOf(HelloActor.props()) ! ${definedClass.companion}("abc")
 """

tb.eval(actorCode) // case object instance has been received!
```

Scala 2.13.8