# Using Scala Toolbox is it possible to define a case class and use it later into eval code?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, compiler-construction, toolbox

I would like to give the case class definition to the Toolbox and be able to use them later when I do the eval. The Toolbox should be able to know the definitions of the case classes.

For example,
I am able to define a case class named Authentication with args email

```
      import scala.reflect.runtime._
      import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
      import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
      val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
      val toolBox = cm.mkToolBox()
      val myClass: ClassDef = q"case class Authentication(email: String)".asInstanceOf[ClassDef]
      val definedClass  = toolBox.define(myClass)
      println(definedClass)
```

It prints `class Authentication`
Then I would like to recall it into my Eval expression and match it

```
  val myCode =
    q""" def myFunction(x:Any){
       x match{
        case Authentication(param) => println("Auth received!")
        }
       }"""

  toolBox.eval(myCode)
```

But it tells me, Authentication was not found.
Any idea of how to accomplish it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala reflection: how do I define a case class at runtime and then reference to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854771/scala-reflection-how-do-i-define-a-case-class-at-runtime-and-then-reference-to)

Comment: @cchantep Unfortunately not.

Comment: Yes it is, if you read the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.apply` and `.unapply` are methods of companion object, you missed `.companion` similarly to [Scala reflection: how do I define a case class at runtime and then reference to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854771/scala-reflection-how-do-i-define-a-case-class-at-runtime-and-then-reference-to)

Try

```
val myCode =
  q"""
    def myFunction(x: Any) = {
      x match{
        case ${definedClass.companion}(param) => println("Auth received!")
      }
    }

    myFunction(${definedClass.companion}("111@aaa"))
  """

toolBox.eval(myCode) // Auth received!
```